# Transition to 3.5 to 3.6 - Geometry Nodes does not render alpha channel mesh properly

Tags: geometry-nodes, transparency

Mesh on the right displays alpha channel correctly in both versions.

Mesh on the left is a geometry node that uses the "Object Info" node to display that mesh. As you can see you get different results in 3.6

I have tried to do a simple "Object Info" plugged into the Group Output and it works in 3.6, but it does not on my main geometry node networks and there is not a single node with a warning or any sign of error.

Have you guys experienced anything similar? It is driving me nuts.

[image]

Comment: If you try the same file and it works in 3.5 but not in 3.6, then I think you should report a bug.

Comment: Reported the bug and it was resolved within 2 hours. Thank you! It was a problem regarding UVMap name from the mesh. The geometry node was reading 2 of them causing a conflict. Something it was ignored in 3.5 but now it is strict in 3.6

Comment: @RicardoMartinez, please observe the format and rules of this platform. If you find a solution, you should post an answer even if it's your own question as opposed to adding the word "SOLVED" in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to a conflict between 2 UV Maps. The source mesh had a UV Map name that was not referenced in the geometry nodes network.

The solution was to get rid of it and stick with the default UVMap attribute.